# NHibernate Left Join with condition or null

Tags: nhibernate

I have 2 objects, `Project` and `UsageLast30` mapped as one-to-one.

I am trying to query for all Projects which either don't have a UsageLast30 yet, or have a UsageLast30 with a date property before a threshold.

I get a null reference exception if I use the query:

```
session.QueryOver<Project>(() => p)
    .Left.JoinAlias(() => p.UsageLast30, () => u)
    .Where(() => u == null || u.LastCalculated < threshold)
```

The following alternative runs, but doesn't not produce the SQL I would expect.

```
session.QueryOver<Project>(() => p)
    .Left.JoinAlias(() => p.UsageLast30, () => u)
    .Where(Restrictions.Or(
        Restrictions.Where<Project>(x => x.UsageLast30 == null),
        Restrictions.Where(() => u.LastCalculated < threshold)
    ))
```

This gives a WHERE condition of:

```
WHERE  (this_.project_id is null
     or u1_.last_calculated < '2015-09-08T18:18:51' /* @p0 */)
```

The `null` test is on Project, not on UsageLast30 as I would expect.

How can I build this query?

Mapping as follows:

```
<class name="Analytics.Core.Project" table="project">
    <id name="Id" column="project_id">
      <generator class="identity" />
    </id>
    <!-- ... -->
    <one-to-one name="UsageLast30" constrained="false" foreign-key="none" />
</class>

<class name="Analytics.Core.ProjectUsageLast30" table="project_usage30">
    <id name="ProjectId" column="project_id">
        <generator class="foreign">
            <param name="property">Project</param>
        </generator>
    </id>
    <!-- ... -->
    <one-to-one name="Project" constrained="true" />
</class>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I still don't know why testing for null on `p.UsageLast30` generates the wrong null test, but testing for a null **property** rather than a null **object** gives the correct SQL query. For example:

```
session.QueryOver<Project>(() => p)
    .Left.JoinAlias(() => p.UsageLast30, () => u)
    .Where(() => u.LastCalculated == null || u.LastCalculated < threshold)
```

Notice the `u.LastCalculated == null` compared to `u == null`